# SideMenu coming separately in updated macOS catalina and updated Xcode 11.2.1 in swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, storyboard, uistoryboardsegue, side-menu

I have recently updated macos from mojave to catalina and xcode from 10.14 to 11.1.2. in previous version i am getting sidemenu properly but in updated version side menu coming separately, why?

i have installed pod `pod 'SideMenu'` in progect and i have created SideMenuNavigationController and Sets the button's Triggered Segues action to modally present.. this was working fine in previous version but in updated version its coming separately like below.

[image]

I didn't change code from previous version to updated version but it coming like this, please help me in this issue.side

Comment: Because they used modal presentation for side menu effect and now modal presentation looks in this way on iOS... side-effect of unintended usage of default feature, which changed on new iOS version.

Comment: @Asperi,then how can i get sidemenu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your storyboard

Click on the view of this sidemenu

In the attribute inspector (4th icon) on sidemenu, click on

'Presentation Style', change it to Full Screen or Over Full Screen. By default now these views use a different style and sometimes this causes your app to crash !

If it doesn't work, click on the segue connecting your original view to 'side menu navigation controller' and click on the 4th icon in the attribute inspector.

Do these changes

```
Kind - Present Modally
Presentation -  Same as Destination (or full screen)
Transition -  Same as Destination (or full screen)
```

On  'side menu navigation controller' on attribute inspector click on 4th icon, then do these

```
Transition Style -  Cover Vertical
Presentation -  Full Screen
```